# Cast JSON to a new model (including it's own casts)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-7

I would like to solve the following thing: I got a model including a JSON-object. This JSON is representing a `Product`, but it should not be synced with the actual `Product` as it should be "alive" even if the product is being deleted. Additionally the JSON may contain custom information about the `Product`.

If I call my model `Product`, I'd like to make sure that specific information within this JSON are casted just like the original `Product`. So `product->price` should always be a `decimal:2`. Even if the JSON may contain a string with the value `1.99`.

As I am not able to "deep cast" the JSON, I am looking at the `Castables` (https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#custom-casts)

Would this be the way to go? And: Can I somehow import the `casts` of the `Product` model there?

This is the model called `Position`:

```
class Position extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable
        = [
            'product'
        ];

    /**
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts
        = [
            'product'          => 'object'
        ];

    /**
     * Get the owning positionable model.
     */
    public function positionable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
```

### So my question is:

Is it possible to cast the `product` JSON in my `Position` model just like the `Product` model **without** creating a relation?

Comment: I have no clue what you're wanting to do

Comment: I added a more specific question to the end.

Comment: You can define custom casts where the type is a model. The Laravel documentation even includes an example: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#value-object-casting